# multiplying columns of tableview using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, javafx

In a javafx program, I need to multiply the value of two columns and output the result in another. I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29589219/javafx-tableview-column-value-dependent-on-other-columns) answer, but I am having some troubles.
Consider also that I am using hibernate.
When I run:

```
String sQuery = "from Magazzino";
```

I get this error message

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
... 52 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.InstantiationException: No default constructor for entity:  : entities.Magazzino
at org.hibernate.tuple.PojoInstantiator.instantiate(PojoInstantiator.java:120)
at org.hibernate.tuple.PojoInstantiator.instantiate(PojoInstantiator.java:136)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.instantiate(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:737)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.instantiate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4755)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.instantiate(SessionImpl.java:1387)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.instantiate(SessionImpl.java:1375)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1618)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1514)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:725)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:952)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:920)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2551)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2537)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2367)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2362)
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:496)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:229)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1260)
at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
at gestionale_officina_app_fxml_1.FXMLDocumentController.parseTuttiProdottiList(FXMLDocumentController.java:347)
at gestionale_officina_app_fxml_1.FXMLDocumentController.cercaTuttiProdotti(FXMLDocumentController.java:361)
... 62 more
```

There must be something wrong in the class below, but I do not understand what it could be.

```
package entities;
// Generated 4-gen-2018 15.43.44 by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1

import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.binding.NumberBinding;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="MAGAZZINO"
,schema="ALBI"
)
public class Magazzino implements java.io.Serializable{

private final SimpleIntegerProperty itemId;
private final SimpleStringProperty itemNome;
private final SimpleStringProperty itemCodice;
private final SimpleStringProperty itemBrand;
private final SimpleStringProperty itemDescrizione;
private final SimpleStringProperty itemTipo;
private final SimpleStringProperty itemSottotipo;
private final SimpleStringProperty itemFornitore1;
private final SimpleStringProperty itemFornitore2;
private final SimpleDoubleProperty itemPrezzo;
private final SimpleIntegerProperty itemQta;
private final SimpleStringProperty itemQtaSoglia;
private final SimpleStringProperty itemLocation;
private final SimpleDoubleProperty itemValoreTot;     

private Magazzino(int itemId, String itemNome, String itemCodice, String itemBrand, String itemDescrizione, String itemTipo, String itemSottotipo, String itemFornitore1, String itemFornitore2, Double itemPrezzo, Integer itemQta, String itemQtaSoglia, String itemLocation, Double itemValoreTot) {
   this.itemId = new SimpleIntegerProperty(itemId);
   this.itemNome = new SimpleStringProperty(itemNome);
   this.itemCodice = new SimpleStringProperty(itemCodice);
   this.itemBrand = new SimpleStringProperty(itemBrand);
   this.itemDescrizione = new SimpleStringProperty(itemDescrizione);
   this.itemTipo = new SimpleStringProperty(itemTipo);
   this.itemSottotipo = new SimpleStringProperty(itemSottotipo);
   this.itemFornitore1 = new SimpleStringProperty(itemFornitore1);
   this.itemFornitore2 = new SimpleStringProperty(itemFornitore2);
   this.itemPrezzo = new SimpleDoubleProperty(itemPrezzo);
   this.itemQta = new SimpleIntegerProperty(itemQta);
   this.itemQtaSoglia = new SimpleStringProperty(itemQtaSoglia);
   this.itemLocation = new SimpleStringProperty(itemLocation);
   this.itemValoreTot = new SimpleDoubleProperty(itemValoreTot);
   NumberBinding multiplication = Bindings.multiply(this.itemPrezzoProperty(), this.itemQtaProperty());
   this.itemValoreTotProperty().bind(multiplication);
}


@Id
@Column(name="ITEM_ID", unique=true, nullable=false)
public int getItemId() {
    return itemId.get();
}

public SimpleIntegerProperty itemIdProperty() {
    return itemId;
}

public void setItemId(int itemId) {
    this.itemId.set(itemId);
}

@Column(name="ITEM_NOME", nullable=false, length=100)
public String getItemNome() {
    return itemNome.get();
}

public SimpleStringProperty itemNomeProperty() {
    return itemNome;
}

public void setItemNome(String itemNome) {
    this.itemNome.set(itemNome);
}

@Column(name="ITEM_CODICE", length=100)
public String getItemCodice() {
    return itemCodice.get();
}

public SimpleStringProperty itemCodiceProperty() {
    return itemCodice;
}

public void setItemCodice(String itemCodice) {
    this.itemCodice.set(itemCodice);
}

@Column(name="ITEM_BRAND", length=100)
public String getItemBrand() {
    return itemBrand.get();
}

public SimpleStringProperty itemBrandProperty() {
    return itemBrand;
}

public void setItemBrand(String itemBrand) {
    this.itemBrand.set(itemBrand);
}

@Column(name="ITEM_DESCRIZIONE", length=100)    
public String getItemDescrizione() {
    return itemDescrizione.get();
}

public SimpleStringProperty itemDescrizioneProperty() {
    return itemDescrizione;
}

public void setItemDescrizione(String itemDescrizione) {
    this.itemDescrizione.set(itemDescrizione);
}  

@Column(name="ITEM_TIPO", length=100)    
public String getItemTipo() {
    return itemTipo.get();
}

public SimpleStringProperty itemTipoProperty() {
    return itemTipo;
}

public void setItemTipo(String itemTipo) {
    this.itemTipo.set(itemTipo);
} 

@Column(name="ITEM_SOTTOTIPO", length=100)
public String getItemSottotipo() {
    return itemSottotipo.get();
}

public SimpleStringProperty itemSottotipoProperty() {
    return itemSottotipo;
}

public void setItemSottotipo(String itemSottotipo) {
    this.itemSottotipo.set(itemSottotipo);
} 

@Column(name="ITEM_FORNITORE_1", length=100)
public String getItemFornitore1() {
    return itemFornitore1.get();
}

public SimpleStringProperty itemFornitore1Property() {
    return itemFornitore1;
}

public void setItemFornitore1(String itemFornitore1) {
    this.itemFornitore1.set(itemFornitore1);
}

@Column(name="ITEM_FORNITORE_2", length=100)
public String getItemFornitore2() {
    return itemFornitore2.get();
}

public SimpleStringProperty itemFornitore2Property() {
    return itemFornitore2;
}

public void setItemFornitore2(String itemFornitore2) {
    this.itemFornitore2.set(itemFornitore2);
}

@Column(name="ITEM_PREZZO")
public Double getItemPrezzo() {
    return itemPrezzo.get();
}

public SimpleDoubleProperty itemPrezzoProperty() {
    return itemPrezzo;
}

public void setItemPrezzo(Double itemPrezzo) {
    this.itemPrezzo.set(itemPrezzo);
} 

@Column(name="ITEM_QTA")
public Integer getItemQta() {
    return itemQta.get();
}

public SimpleIntegerProperty itemQtaProperty() {
    return itemQta;
}

public void setItemQta(Integer itemQta) {
    this.itemQta.set(itemQta);
} 

@Column(name="ITEM_QTA_SOGLIA")
public String getItemQtaSoglia() {
    return itemQtaSoglia.get();
}

public SimpleStringProperty itemQtaSogliaProperty() {
    return itemQtaSoglia;
}

public void setItemQtaSoglia(String itemQtaSoglia) {
    this.itemQtaSoglia.set(itemQtaSoglia);
} 

@Column(name="ITEM_LOCATION", length=100)
public String getItemLocation() {
    return itemLocation.get();
}

public SimpleStringProperty itemLocationProperty() {
    return itemLocation;
}

public void setitemLocation(String itemLocation) {
    this.itemLocation.set(itemLocation);
} 

@Column(name="ITEM_VALORE_TOT")
public Double getItemValoreTot() {
    return itemValoreTot.get();
}

public SimpleDoubleProperty itemValoreTotProperty() {
    return itemValoreTot;
}

public void setItemValoreTot(Double itemValoreTot) {
    this.itemValoreTot.set(itemValoreTot);
}
}
```

Comment: The solution in the duplicate question erases this error: variable itemId might not have been initialized.

Comment: referred to my previous comment, I added --->> public Magazzino(){}

Comment: This is what I did to solve my problem. In practice, before calling the query above, I simply did an update query with the moltiplication operation between price and qta. Doing so the column with total will have the the correct value and I do not have to modify the class generated with the netbeans hibernate wizard. p.s. It was so simple and fast. Thanks Alb